# Send file via postman

Tags: php, json, laravel, postman

I am trying to send files like images via postman but not in form-data,
I mean here in this area:

[image]

please help me how to do that from here

Comment: What format are you intending that file to take?  Maybe base-64 encode it into a string and send that string?

Comment: I do not know what to do, but is necessary to send from raw, what is best solution? @David

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you must send json then you need to encode image as base64 use this [tool](https://www.base64decode.org/) and send it as encoded string.

Otherwise just send it through form data like below:

[image]

Comment: @amini.swallow then encode it as base 64 on that online tool and send it as encoded string .

Comment: @amini.swallow go to site above upload image encoe copy the encoded big string and paste it on your json  "file": "long encoded 64 string paste it here"